Fibrating $S^3$ by taking cosets of a subgroup of $SU_2$
So I was reading the Chapter 8 on Linear Groups of Michael Artin's Algebra textbook and I came across the term "Hopf Fibration", on looking it up on the internet, I found it's too deep a topic and it's beyond me to comprehend most parts of it. But I'd just want to know whether my understanding on a very elementary level of it makes any sense.
$\textbf{My understanding:}$
We want to see how the $3$-sphere ($S^3$) can be made up by taking unions of disjoint great circles of $S^3$, where we define a "great circle" of $S^3$ by the intersection of $S^3$ with a $2$-dim subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.
Now we identify $S^3$ as $SU_2$ and $S_2$ as the set of all trace $0$ matrices in $SU_2$, and defining the map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ by $$\pi\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ -\overline{b} & \overline{a}\end{bmatrix}\right)= \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ -\overline{b} & \overline{a}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 &-i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ -\overline{b} & \overline{a}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$ it can be proven that the fibres of $\pi$ are sets of the for $QT$ where $Q\in SU_2$ and $T\le SU_2$ defined by $T=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0\\ 0 & \overline{\lambda}\end{bmatrix} \mid \lambda\overline{\lambda}=1\right\}$ is a subgroup of $SU_2$. Now obviously the map $\mathbb{R^{2\times 2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{2\times 2}}$ defined by $T\mapsto QT$ where $Q\in SU_2$ is an invertible linear operator on $\mathbb{R^{2\times 2}}$ and thus the subspace $(w_1,w_2,0,0)$ maps to a $2-$ dim subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$, from where it's obvious that the sets of the form $QT$ where $Q\in SU_2$ correspond to intersections of a $2$- dim subspace of $R^4$ and $S^3$ and hence great circle, and since they are the cosets of $T$, their disjoint union will be $SU_2$, thus geometrically we get a fibration of $SU_2$ by great circles.
Question:   If we were to do the same thing with $S^2$,then any two great circles of $S^2$, if I'm not mistaken will intersect at two antipodal points, and hence will always intersect. But with the way we fibrated $S^3$ by the cosets $QT$, the great circles wouldn't intersect. So does this have to do anything with the dimension of the sphere? I'd be highly obliged, if someone could explain it to me on a very basic level!

Instead of viewing $S^3$ as $SU(2)$, it is easier to understand the Hopf fibration by viewing it as the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^2$.  Moreover, this approach is preferable because it immediately generalizes to all odd-dimensional spheres.
The point is that the complex numbers of unit length act on $S^3$ via multiplication by scalar matrices, resulting in a fibration of $S^3$ by great circles of a special type (namely, orbits under this action of $S^1$).
